# How to improve speed when getting latitudes and longitudes with Python Mapbox?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mapbox

I'm trying to get geographic coordinates with mapbox API. Code is below. The issue is that the for loop runs very slow, probably cos my dataframe has more than 500K rows. Is there a faster/more efficient way of doing this?

PS: By the way I'm not sure I built the dictionary correctly. I don't know if it will work, since the parser hasn't yet executed it due to its slowness in executing the for loop.

```py
# create instance of MapBox Geocoder with access token
geocoder = Geocoder(access_token="---")
    
# create empty lists for geographic coordinates
coords = []
    
# since we have duplicate values in Address column, it'll be more performant
# to geocode for each unique value get all unique values
addresses = df['Address'].str.lower().unique()
    
# create for loop to populate the geographic coordinates lists based 
# on each unique address
for i in range(len(addresses)):
    response = geocoder.forward(addresses[i])
    coords.append(response.geojson()["features"][0]["center"])
        
# create a dictionary of addresses and their coordinates
d = dict(
        zip(
            addresses, 
            pd.Series(coords)
        )
    )

# map coordinates to their addresses and store in a new column
df['Coords'] = df['Address'].map(d)
```

Comment: You could make it somewhat faster by making multiple requests in parallel, but the gain is limited: given a [600 requests/minute limit](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#geocoding-restrictions-and-limits), this will take at minimum 13 hours.

Comment: please can you show me how to make multiple requests in parallel? I will reduce the data to avoid the 13-hour run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with [ThreadPool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) and [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) from Python standard library's multiprocessing module:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import pandas as pd
from mapbox import Geocoder


def func(address):
    """Helper function."""
    response = geocoder.forward(address)
    return {address: pd.Series(response.geojson()["features"][0]["center"])}


MAX_REQUESTS = 599  # requests
TIME_LIMIT = 60  # seconds

geocoder = Geocoder(access_token="---")
addresses = df["Address"].str.lower().unique()
chunks_of_adresses = [
    addresses[i : i + MAX_REQUESTS] for i in range(0, len(addresses), MAX_REQUESTS)
]  # [[0, 598], [599, 1197], ...]
results = []  # will be a list of lists of dictionaries

for chunk in chunks_of_adresses:
    start = time.time()
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        result = pool.map(func, chunk)  # 'result' is a list of dictionaries
        results.append(result)
    if (elapsed := time.time() - start) <= TIME_LIMIT:
        time.sleep(TIME_LIMIT - elapsed)

# merge lists of dictionaries into one dictionary
adresses_and_coords = {
    address: series
    for result in results
    for pair in result
    for address, series in pair.items()
}

# map coordinates to their addresses and store in a new column
df["Coords"] = df["Address"].map(adresses_and_coords)
```